# Saving results of Do Loop in .csv

Tags: mathematical-optimization, export, data

I am very inexperienced with Mathematica and I am short of time so I need to move the results on py/r to plot and analyze

I have done an optimization with NMaximize of this type:

```
pif[d_, beta_, alpha_, 
  theta_] := ((-1 + d) (-d (-2 + theta) + theta)^2)/(
 16 (-1 + d + 2 alpha (-1 + beta) d))
Do[Print[  {m1 = 
    NMaximize[{pif[d, beta, alpha, theta], 0 <= d <= 1, 
      theta - 1 <= (-theta + 
        d (2 + theta + 4 alpha (-1 + beta) theta))/(
       2 (-1 + d + 2 alpha (-1 + beta) d)) <= theta}, {d}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 6], alpha, beta, theta}], {alpha, 0, 1, 
  1/10}, {beta, 0, 1, 1/10}, {theta, 1, 3, 1/10}]
```

Now I would like to create a .csv/txt file unpacking the elements of m1 such as:

f,d,alpha,beta,theta
0.111095,0.333237,0,0,1
...,...,...,...,...

How can I export such a file?

for now I can do:

```
outfile = "results.txt";
Put[outfile];
Do[m1 = NMaximize[{pif[d, beta, alpha, theta], 0 <= d <= 1, 
    theta - 1 <= (-theta + 
      d (2 + theta + 4 alpha (-1 + beta) theta))/(
     2 (-1 + d + 2 alpha (-1 + beta) d)) <= theta}, {d}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 6]; {m1, alpha, beta, theta} >>> 
  outfile, {alpha, 0, 1, 1/2}, {beta, 0, 1, 1/2}, {theta, 1, 3, 1/2}]
```

But I hate the fact that the final file is:

```
{{0.1110949906925870948`6., {d -> 0.3332366073137181589`6.}}, 0, 0, 1}
{{0.159995395724830863`6., {d -> 0.1999539569170640224`6.}}, 0, 0, 3/2}
{{0.25`6., {d -> 0}}, 0, 0, 2}
```

And need to use py to clean it

Answer (score 1):

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
pif[d_, beta_, alpha_, 
  theta_] := ((-1 + d) (-d (-2 + theta) + theta)^2)/(16 (-1 + d + 2 alpha (-1 + beta) d))

data = Last@Reap@Do[
     m1 = Quiet@Check[NMaximize[
         {pif[d, beta, alpha, theta], 0 <= d <= 1, 
          theta - 1 <= (-theta + 
              d (2 + theta + 4 alpha (-1 + beta) theta))/(2 (-1 + d + 
                2 alpha (-1 + beta) d)) <= theta}, {d}, 
         WorkingPrecision -> 6], $Failed
        ];
     If[m1 =!= $Failed,
      m1[[2]] = d /. m1[[2]];
      Sow[Flatten@{m1, N@alpha, N@beta, N@theta}]
      ]
     ,
     {alpha, 0, 1, 1/10},
     {beta, 0, 1, 1/10},
     {theta, 1, 1, 1/10}
     ];
 data = Flatten[data, 1];
 Export["data.csv", data]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd need hours just to understand the steps, however that is exactly the solution I was looking for. I'll study when I'll have more time

Comment: @KArrow'sBest note that I added `Check` there because when I run your code NMinimize was generating warnings `NMinimize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the 
inequality constraints` and this check is there to bypass such cases as I assume you do not want these and only want to save only results generated with no error or warnings.

Comment: I noticed also the if condition. On my machine it doesn't give any warning! however I would rather keep the line that failed, so that I am aware of it

Comment: @KArrow'sBest  Yes, the Check will trap any messages, warning or errors.  and  convert these all $Failed. If you want to hear the beeps and see the  warning messages but still want to trap them, just remove the `Quite` command. Now you will hear the beeps, but these result will still filtered out.

Comment: thank you, but again removed `Quite' and no beep heard!

Comment: @KArrow'sBest You need to increase the last entry theta to `3` to see the warnings. Like this  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jkKF.png)  which is what you had in your original code. I changed to go to 1 only since it was slow otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140440/discussion-between-karrowsbest-and-nasser).

Answer (score 1):

So, lot's of stuff going on that I don't understand, but I think I can help with getting the data cleaner. First off, don't use `Do` + `Print`. Just create your data directly. Something like Table would work.

```
result =
  Table[
    {NMaximize[<...stuff...>],
     alpha,
     beta,
     theta},
    {alpha, 0, 1, 1/10}, {beta, 0, 1, 1/10}, {theta, 1, 3, 1/10}]
```

Now, result will have too much depth. So flatten it:

```
flatResult = Flatten /@ Flatten[result, 2]
```

That looks a bit jenky, and there's probably a more elegant way to do it, but anyway, now you have flat "rows".

The `d -> 0.333237` stuff needs to be cleaned up:

```
cleanResult = flatResult /. rule_Rule :> rule[[2]]
```

Okay, now you ought to be able to just Export:

```
Export["filename", cleanResult]
```

For what it's worth, I saw lots of error messages when I ran your Do loop, so the above isn't really tested and I don't know what will happen for the invalid data.